# Not able to secure website on Firefox even after installing SSL certificate

Tags: node.js, firefox, amazon-ec2, ssl-certificate

I am using the below code to install SSL certificate on my website:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
const fs= require('fs');
let privateKey = fs.readFileSync('certificate/x.key', 'utf8');
let ca = fs.readFileSync('certificate/x.crt', 'utf8');
let certificate = fs.readFileSync('certificate/x.crt', 'utf8');
let credentials = { key: privateKey, cert: certificate, ca: ca };
const http = require('http');
const https = require('https');

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));

app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});

let httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app);

httpsServer.listen(443);
```

This is a react app and I am serving it via Node.js.

When I open the website on Chrome or Microsoft Edge, it shows the connection as secure, encrypted and valid but when I open it on firefox, it shows that the connection is not secure.
[image: Valid in Chrome]
[image: Not working in Firefox]

What could be the problem?

Comment: Is firefox reading the right certificate? Also did you clear cache and check?

Comment: How should I verify that it is reading the right certificate? It is working in chrome and Edge though. Yes, I cleared the cache and the problem is still there

Comment: Just click on Advanced, navigate to site and check what certificate did site loaded.

Comment: Error code is : SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER  and when I click on it, it shows a certificate which I did not pass into the code.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Who is the issuer of the certificate?

Comment: Digicert is the issuer

Comment: Okay, Who is your actual certificate issuer? Like what is the issuer name in chrome and edge?

Comment: Is the URL public? You might try Qualys SSL Server Test which is pretty good at identifying problems. If I had to guess, I'd guess you were giving it the site cert but not the full chain that includes the intermediate. If the other browsers key stores have the intermediate cert, they'll work but browsers lacking that cert won't.

Answer (score 1):

If your intermediate certificate contains multiple blocks, then you should split them into different files and send them one-by-one as an array in ca parameter like this:

```
let credentials = { key: privateKey, cert: certificate, ca: [
    fs.readFileSync('certificate/x_1.pem', 'utf8'),
    fs.readFileSync('certificate/x_2.pem', 'utf8'),
    fs.readFileSync('certificate/x_3.pem', 'utf8'),
    [...]
] };
```

Answer (score 0):

If your certificate looks correct on other Browsers and simply does not appear in Firefox, the reason is almost certainly, that Firefox still shows a cached certificate.

Simply clear Firefox's SSL state and you should be good to go:

- On the History menu, click Clear Recent History. The Clear All History dialog appears.
- In the Time range to clear list box, select Everything.
- Select the Active Logins check box.
- Click Clear Now.

Source: 
https://www.a2hosting.co.uk/kb/getting-started-guide/internet-and-networking/clearing-a-web-browsers-ssl-state#Mozilla-Firefox

Comment: Its not a issue with history. I cleared,deleted and reinstalled the browser but it is still not working

Comment: I think the firefox certificates can sometimes be hard to get rid off. Try "refreshing" your installation via the way described in the official docs: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/refresh-firefox-reset-add-ons-and-settings?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=reset-firefox-easily-fix-most-problems Also, use an SSL checker, such as https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html to test your certificate.

Comment: What does the SSL checker say? Is it showing the correct certificate? What happens if you try Firefox on a different computer?

Comment: I tried firefox on mac and the HTTPS works fine but if I try the same on firfox for Windows, it shows the same error

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to enter your site address [here](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/) and test it for issues.

If you see, e.g. full chain not provided issue, you can create a full chain of all your certificates and PEM-encode it into a single cert file, then provide it as a cert file. You can even download this full chain there directly after the test, too.

Providing a full chain fixed issues for me several times, where everything worked fine in chrome, but not in some other cases.

Comment: My Overall rating is A. And is trusted by Mozilla, Apple, Android, Java and Windows